# Maven build is failing in Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins

I'm trying to learn how `Jenkins` works so I started a sample maven project and I'm trying to build it through `Jenkins`. Even though the project can be build by using `cmd` I'm getting following error when I try to build the project using `Jenkins`

Can someone give me a solution

```
Parsing POMs
ERROR: Failed to parse POMs
hudson.maven.MavenEmbedderException: 1 problem was encountered while building the effective settings
[FATAL] Non-readable settings C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.2.3: C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.2.3 (Access is denied) @ C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.2.3

at hudson.maven.MavenEmbedder.<init>(MavenEmbedder.java:128)
at hudson.maven.MavenEmbedder.<init>(MavenEmbedder.java:109)
at hudson.maven.MavenEmbedder.<init>(MavenEmbedder.java:136)
at hudson.maven.MavenUtil.createEmbedder(MavenUtil.java:212)
at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$PomParser.invoke(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1285)
at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$PomParser.invoke(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1088)
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:991)
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:969)
at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.parsePoms(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:950)
at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.doRun(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:677)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:537)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1741)
at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:529)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:381)
Caused by: hudson.maven.MavenEmbedderException: 1 problem was encountered while building the effective settings
[FATAL] Non-readable settings C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.2.3: C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.2.3 (Access is denied) @ C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.2.3

at hudson.maven.MavenEmbedder.getSettings(MavenEmbedder.java:261)
at hudson.maven.MavenEmbedder.buildMavenExecutionRequest(MavenEmbedder.java:157)
at hudson.maven.MavenEmbedder.<init>(MavenEmbedder.java:120)
... 14 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.settings.building.SettingsBuildingException: 1 problem was encountered while building the effective settings
[FATAL] Non-readable settings C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.2.3: C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.2.3 (Access is denied) @ C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.2.3

at org.apache.maven.settings.building.DefaultSettingsBuilder.build(DefaultSettingsBuilder.java:116)
at hudson.maven.MavenEmbedder.getSettings(MavenEmbedder.java:259)
... 16 more
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, apparently you have no access to `C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.2.3`. Do you have a settings file in there? If so, you can store the settings file in the .m2 folder in your home directory. Copy the folder into your user directory and try again.

Comment: @madu Is the errorlog still containing something about `C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.2.3`?

Comment: Then it is still accessing the wrong maven installation. Are you using an IDE? If so, which one?

Answer (score 0):

Move your Maven to another directory other that C:\Program Files.
or provide full access permissions to C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.2.3